# How to export results from bootstrapping in R?

Tags: r, export-to-csv, statistics-bootstrap

I have a time series of 540 observations which I resample 999 times using the following code:

```
boot.mean = function(x,i){boot.mean = mean(x[i])}
z1 = boot(x1, boot.mean, R=999)
z1
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Call:
boot(data = x1, statistic = boot.mean, R = 999)

Bootstrap Statistics :
        original        bias    std. error
t1* -0.009381397 -5.903801e-05 0.002524366
```

trying to export the results gives me the following error:

```
write.csv(z1, "z1.csv")

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""boot"" to a data.frame
```

How can I export the results to a .csv file?

I am expecting to obtain a file with 540 observations 999 times, and the goal is to apply the `approx_entropy` function from the `pracma` package, to obtain 999 values for approximate entropy and plot the distribution in Latex.

Comment: Hint: look at str(z1).

Comment: Thank you. I tried `write.csv(str(z1), "z1.csv")` however the file z1.csv is blank.

Comment: I meant look at the output of it. The values are stored in z1$t.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, please make sure that your example is reproducible. You can do so by generating a small `x1` object, or by generating a random `x1` vector:

```
> x1 <- rnorm(540)
```

Now, from your question:

> I am expecting to obtain a file with 540 observations 999 times

However, this is not what you will get. You are generating 999 repetitions of the **mean** of the resampled data. That means that every bootstrap replicate is actually a single number.

From Heroka's comment:

> Hint: look at str(z1).

The function `str` shows you the actual data inside the z1 object, without the pretty formatting.

```
> str(z1)
 List of 11
 $ t0       : num 0.0899
 $ t        : num [1:999, 1] 0.1068 0.1071 0.0827 0.1413 0.0914 ...
 $ R        : num 999
 $ data     : num [1:540] 1.02 1.27 1.82 -2.92 0.68 ...
 (... lots of irrelevant stuff here ...)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "boot"
```

So your original data is stored as `z1$data`, and the data that you have bootstraped, which is the **mean** of each resampling, is stored in `z1$t`. Notice how it tells you the dimension of each slot: `z1$t` is 999 x 1.

Now, what you *probably* want to do is change the `boot.mean` function by a `boot.identity` function, which simply returns the resampled data. It goes like:

```
> boot.identity = function(x,i){x[i]}
> z1 = boot(x1, boot.identity, R=999)
> str(z1)
List of 11
 $ t0       : num [1:540] 1.02 1.27 1.82 -2.92 0.68 ...
 $ t        : num [1:999, 1:540] -0.851 -0.434 -2.138 0.935 -0.493 ...
 $ R        : num 999
 $ data     : num [1:540] 1.02 1.27 1.82 -2.92 0.68 ...
(... etc etc etc ...)
```

And you can save this data with `write.csv(z1$t, "z1.csv")`.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you very much.